# How to make Docky appear over other windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, dock, docky

I installed Docky in Ubuntu and I have it set to autohide. One problem is that if a window is maximized, then the docky is blocked. In order to see it, I have to unmaximize or moved windows. Can docky be made to appear above other windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `devilspie` to handle several behaviours under your Gnome's window manager, for instance the "always on top" you are searching for. [Here's an example](http://www.redips.net/linux/gnome-always-on-top/).